# Where is HttpContext.User property set initially?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

HttpContext has a **User** property which treats IPrincipal type.
From the documentation of MS I know the property might be set by Http-modules such as **WindowsAuthenticationModule** or **FormsAuthenticationModule**
But, for example, this is code of **WindowsAuthenticationModule**:

```
 WindowsPrincipal user = context.User as WindowsPrincipal;
        if (user != null) {/* code... */}
```

it's interesting that if the condition is false (user is null or user has other type, not WindowsPrincipal) than **WindowsAuthenticationModule** return control (for intagrated mode pipeline of IIS).
I have the following questions:

1. After IIS authenticates the client (as anonymous or authenticated user, as it was configured) it will pass a security token to ASP.NET. Our application in any case wrapps this token in **WindowsIdentity** и **WindowsPrincipal** objects. It happens before authentication modules begin implementing.
   Is this true?
2. If the 1 is true, where is HttpContext.User property set initially?
3. If the 1 is true, when HttpContext.User is null? I guess it's might be if I configure Web.config :

   < authentication mode="None" />

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the HttpContext.User is set when the user is authenticated (not anonymously).  I know that in FormsAuthentication this happens on `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` and the HttpContext.User is set to null when the client logs out and the cookie is cleared